# Sub-Report giving error: Report cannot be shown

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS Report with six sub-reports. The sub-reports are using the same shared data source which the main report is using.

When I deploy the report and execute, the sub-report place holder shows error: Report cannot be shown.

I thought it could be due to shared data source. Therefore, I created separate shared data source for each sub-report. This works. The report starts showing all the results.

Please let me know what is this issue. Even though it works, I don't want to create separate shared data source for each sub report.

Comment: Simply delete the subreport from the report and again add it back. The way MS is, that might work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known defect in SSRS 2008.  I'm not sure if it has been patched yet, but it has been fixed  in SSRS 2012.

As you have found, the workaround is to use separate datasets.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/648560/subreport-with-shared-dataset-throws-error